# Visual Studio Code Deploy Issue

Tags: apex, deployment, error, vs-code

I am trying to deploy an utility class by adding a small method. The method implementation is below.

```
public static boolean isId(String strValue) {
    return strValue instanceOf Id;
}
```

When I try the option "Deploy to Source Org", I am getting the following error message.

```
19:53:04.627 Starting Deploy (Beta)
When retrieving results with Metadata or FullName fields, the query qualificatio​ns must      
specify no more than one row for retrieval. Result size: 2
```

Has anyone experienced this? In my package.xml, I only have few apex classes and nothing else.

Can someone help?

Comment: Deploy to Source Org doesn't use a package.xml. Perhaps you have two classes with the same name in that org? I've had that happen before.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess that was it. There are two util classes in my organization, one from a managed package, one is our custom code.